# AppleScript choose file dialog box with default location not working

Tags: applescript

So there goes four hours of my life that I will never get back.

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple...

I want to open a file select dialog box and specify the default location.

I actually got this to work using the following...

```
choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} 
default location "/Users/lowken/Dropbox/"
```

This works and does exactly what I want (the file dialog opens up in the Dropbox folder).

However when I try to use a string variable it doesn't work...

```
set strPath to "/Users/lowken/Dropbox/"

choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} 
default location strPath
```

Now the dialog box opens in the root directory of the hard drive :-(

It seems that the default location is being ignored however if the path is not correct Applescript does raise a error.

I've tried casting the value as a string. I even tried to use the POSIX format...

```
"Macintosh HD:Users:lowken:Dropbox"
```

This didn't format didn't work at all.

I'm running OS X Yosemite 10.10.4 on a mid 2012 MacBook Pro.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default location` of `choose file` expects an alias specifier rather than a POSIX path. This is a user and startup disk name independent solution

```
set dropboxFolder to (path to home folder as text) & "Dropbox"
choose file with prompt "Please choose a file:" of type {"XLSX", "APPL"} default location alias dropboxFolder
```

Comment: That did it. I would have never figured that one out. Thanks!